# GDAL python Image Projection

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system

Running algorithm via window operation for output, it indulge pixel shift.

[image: with ArcGIS projection tool]

[image: With the Code]

This pixel shift is 2 rows down and 1 column right.

CODE:

```
def GetToUTM(Data, pixel_sz, Zone):

gdal.Open('\\myData\\asterDem.tif')
Past_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
Past_ref.ImportFromWkt(Data.GetProjectionRef())
newref = osr.SpatialReference()
newref.SetUTM(abs(Zone),Zone > 0)
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(Past_ref, newref)
geotransform = Data.GetGeoTransform()
nx, ny = Data.RasterXSize, Data.RasterYSize
print nx,ny
(ulx, uly, ulz) = transform.TransformPoint(geotransform[0], geotransform[3])
(lrx, lry, lrz) = transform.TransformPoint(geotransform[0]+ geotransform[1] * nx, geotransform[3] +
                                           geotransform[5] * ny)
getfile = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dataout = getfile.Create('PyAster.tif', int((lrx-ulx)/pixel_sz), int((uly-lry)/pixel_sz), 1, gdal.GDT_Float64)
newGeoTrnsm = (ulx, pixel_sz, geotransform[2], uly, geotransform[4], -pixel_sz)
dataout.SetGeoTransform(newGeoTrnsm)
dataout.SetProjection(newref.ExportToWkt())
gdal.ReprojectImage(Data, dataout, Past_ref.ExportToWkt(), newref.ExportToWkt(), gdal.GRA_NearestNeighbour)

dataout = gdal.Open('\\untitled\\name_sake.tif')'
```

---

The Image is getting re-projected and pixel issue is resolved under my threshold.

Now that original image has value of range from 100-1211(float64), re-projected one report it from 0- 1190.43(float64) which is incorrect.

How can I make the necessary correction?

Comment: I suggest you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/216016/edit) your question to specify how you projected your raster using gdal - i.e. commandline `gdalwarp`, or the gdal API in a programming language like python and what exactly were your projection parameters?

Comment: Thanks @Luke, but i have not used _gdalwarp_ , instead called the image old reference and converted to new reference as said in point 1 of my question. I tried to project image using code but ended up in SpatialReference error so used ArcGIS to project in WGS84 (which is the old reference) and see if the other half , that is, my projection conversion script worked.

Comment: Your code has serious errors that make it un-runnable. Consider rewriting the code to provide a working example.

Comment: @LoganByers Can you suggest some correction?

Comment: @Anvesh Could you provide the code to produce the result that you write about?

Comment: @LoganByers Fine I can do that, actually this part which I have enclosed in my question is for changing projection that got me output to black image. Also If you see the last two images you can easily tell the shift. Is this possible because of bug in library?

Comment: Today I tried the projection in QGIS v.2.16.3, results are positive. I am not misdirected in coding part :) , but still need complete help that which ever platform is used I must get no-shift result. @LoganByers your guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: @Luke  I have made required changes in the code, is there a possible way to avoid giving pixel size, because i think the problem is from there as ArcGIS is making reproction with pixel_sz=11.01967 and I specified 11.02 .

Comment: You say that you "have encountered problems" and it looks like you are asking several questions which makes this too broad.  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo Why have you put the question on hold. I have mentioned that the problem 1,2 were solved by me. But the new issue that came up is range of value...It is assigning it from 0. This is the update.

Comment: If 1,2 are already solved then, since there are no answers, you can simply [edit] them out of your question to leave a single clear question.  This is what we are always looking for when we do focussed Q&A, and focussed Q&A is all that we do here.

Comment: Please take some time to review our advice on [how to ask good questions](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange).  Until you know what potential answerers (who are often the same people who put a question On Hold) are looking for, you are likely to struggle with focussed Q&A.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Thumbs Up